# Perl Use of uninitialized value in string

Tags: perl

"Use of uninitialized value $str1 in string eq at ./script.pl line 20"

not sure why I get this error on line 20, if I comment 20 out, it goes away:

```
 15 ######## HELP section ################
 16 #
 17 our @ARGV;
 18 our ( $str1, $str2 ) = @ARGV;
 19
 20 if ( $str1 eq "help" ) { &help(); }
 21
 22 if ( !$str1 ) { &help(); }
 23 #
 24 sub help {
 25         print <<EOF;
 26         +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 27         +  usage:  $0 "cmd1,cmd2,cmd3" "host1,host2,host3"
 28         +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 29 EOF
 30         exit 0;
 31         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error, it's a warning. It means "$str1" is uninitialized, which in this case means there were no command line arguments specified to the script.

Merge lines 20 and 22 into

```
help() if ! $str1 || $str1 eq 'help';
```

Comment: ty, your solution cleared the error, but wasn't $str1 initialized by "our ( $str1, $str2 ) = @ARGV;"  ?

Comment: @rtep: Only if `@ARGV` wasn't empty, i.e. there were some command line parameters.